# Change of basis in $\Bbb{R^3}$, two methods

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I wish to compute a matrix, that changes coordinates for $v \in \Bbb{R^3}$ with respect to the natural basis into coordinates with respect to basis $E'=(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)).$ It seems like this can be done in two ways. First, I can take the images of the natural basis and write them as unique linear combinations of vectors in $E'$. Then take these coordinates as columns of the matrix $$M(I,N,E')=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0\\0&1&-1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Which gives the coordinates of points in $\Bbb{R^3}$ with respect to basis $E'$. The second way, is to take the matrix $M(I,E',N)$ - whose columns are vectors of $E'$ - and invert it. That is $$(M(I,E',N))^{-1}=M(I,N,E')$$

which again produces the desired matrix. Are these methods equivalent? Is one more general then the other?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.